# Transferring nmap report to excel

Tags: excel, networking, nmap

after running a scan using zenmap (nmap), I ended up with a lot of host reports. Now i have to translate those reports to excel file, so it's easier to read. In the excel file I need to see host ip and open ports. It's my first time doing a job like that, therefore, a step by step guide would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Officially, you can get reports of nmap in XML format refer [this link](https://nmap.org/book/output-formats-xml-output.html).

However, to get it in excel format you might need third-party libraries.

Refer [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9x5qzZLmJ0) for a guide on how to use a popular python library available for this purpose.

You can download the library [from here](https://github.com/mrschyte/nmap-converter).